# Bootstrap Popover is not working when rel is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used the following code to init the bootstrap popover.

**Markup**

```
<a class="help_popup" rel="popover" data-popover-content="#apiSearchTips"  data-placement="bottom">
   <span class="icon fw-stack fw-lg add-margin-left-1x" stylZ="font-size:10px">
       <i class="fw fw-circle fw-stack-2x"></i>
       <i class="fw fw-question fw-stack-1x fw-inverse"></i>
   </span>
</a>

<div id="apiSearchTips" class="hide help-popover-content" >
    //Popover content
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$('a[rel="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    trigger:'click',
    content: function () {
        var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
        return clone;
    }
}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This does not work unless I change the selector attribute to a different one rather than `rel="popover"`. For an example say I change it to `data-trigger="popover"` and it works. Why does this happen?

Comment: Seems to work just fine with the `$('a[rel="popover"]')` selector - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94pht74v/)

Comment: Got it working! I was initializing using two different scripts! Removed one and worked like a charm! :)